# Вопрос по fullpage.js. Как сделать привязку экрана и якоря(кнопки) ведущего на него?

Tags: javascript

Делаю сайт с поэкранным скроллом, для этого использую библиотеку fullpage.js. Имеются кнопки(якоря) к которым привязаны экраны, то есть когда нажимаешь на кнопку происходит скролл до соответствующей секции. Код инициализации следующий:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  //options here
  anchors:['head1', 'head2', 'head3', 'head4', 'head5']
  
});
```

то есть для каждой секции с id head есть соответствующая кнопка с href = head . Мне нужно чтобы при скролле происходило нажатие на эту кнопку и она меняла свой внешний вид, как это реализовано на сайте https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/#page1 . Там это делается через навешивание класса active на кнопку, только как это реализуется не понимаю(

Comment: вы про точечки справа или про какие кнопки с классом active?

Comment: Почитайте документацию. https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/ там есть свойство, которое отвечает за эти точки. navigation...